# Spring Data JPA repository findAll() method returns null List

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using Spring Data JPA:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.2.9.Final.

When I query using findAll, the List returns contains null values.

Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
public class Etudiant implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Serial version UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1982480763983112005L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idEtudiant")
    private Integer idEtudiant;

    @Column(name = "nomEtudiant")
    private String nomEtudiant;

    @Column(name = "prenomEtudiant")
    private String prenomEtudiant;

    @Column(name = "adresse")
    private String adresse;

    @Column(name = "dateNaissance")
    private Date dateNaissance;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "etudiant_cours", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idEtudiant", referencedColumnName = "idEtudiant"), inverseJoinColumns = 
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCours", referencedColumnName = "idCours"))
    private List<Cours> cours;
}
```

NB: Note that the problem is not from lombock, I had tested with getters and setters.

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EtudiantRepository extends JpaRepository<Etudiant, Integer> {     
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class EtudiantServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    EtudiantRepository etudiantRepository;

    List<Etudiant> lst = new ArrayList<Etudiant>();

    public List<Etudiant> getAllEtudiant() {
        lst =  this.etudiantRepository.findAll();
        return lst;
    }
}
```

[image: Debug result]

Comment: What is your `@Entity` class? (Etudiant)

Comment: Yes, Entity is Etudiant

Comment: There is something missing or wrong in your question, but I can´t figure out what it is?!? Is the List null or does it contain null values? What for do You need the member lst in the Repository? Why don´t You show us the sourcecode for your Entity Etundiant? How do you start the debugging-session and when do You take the snapshot?

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: The title of the question is misleading in that it mentions that the repository returns `null`, whereas it is the repository instance itself that is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

In debug screenshot, it can be seen that etudiantRepository is null.
Maybe you are missing @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in your Configuration.

EtudiantServiceImpl is being instantiated using Dependency Injection or with the new keyword?

Comment: Instantiated using Dependency Injection in the Controller

Comment: Are you debugging in a container or using something like junit?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution :

change spring version from 4.3.7.RELEASE to 4.3.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `context:component-scan` annotation into xml configuration for scanning base package and repository package, you can find code below :

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.demo.test.repository" />
<context:component-scan annotation-config="true"
        base-package="com.demo.test" />
```

and if `findall()` return null value that means table dose not having data, it is normal behavior.
 and also check your datasource and entity manager connection

Comment: I already add this configuration to applicationContext.xml, also it create database table from Entity class.